# Can Alexa (echo dot) access a skill that is still in the development mode?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, amazon-echo

I've found [this amazing site](http://skilltemplates.com) to generate my first Alexa skill.

I've uploaded the standard template they have and it passes all the checks.

[image]

**Please note that this skill has not published yet**

and When I say (to the device), `Alexa, open api starter`, Alexa (device) cannot find that. I have an echo dot 2nd gen.

Do we need to publish a skill to be available for the Alexa device?

In my test mode, I've already enabled the Test for this skill.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use the skill locally for development purposes. If you go to the Alexa apps you should see your app located in there and you can then install it. Once installed you can ask Alexa to open the app.

Although, you can't use other peoples apps that are in development because the app is associated with the Amazon account.

Comment: thanks @Joshua, turns out that the issue was my devise was set to AU english and I was developing the skills with US english. Once I changed that, everything started working. :)

Comment: Thank you so much! From the app go to: Home > Skills & Games > Your Skills

Answer (score 4):

You need to register your device to the development account that you are using.

1. Once logged in from your development account go [here](https://alexa.amazon.com/)   (alexa.amazon.com)
2. Go to the settings tab and click set up a new device
3. You will be guided through simple instructions on how to connect your device.

Once you successfully connected the device, you can use all skills from your developer account.

Note: You can have more devices connected to the same developer account, but each device can be connected to just one developer account at a time.

Comment: thanks @Alex, turns out that the issue was my devise was set to AU english and I was developing the skills with US english. Once I changed that, everything started working. :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this doesn't work all the time -  not sure if it's missing information (for instance on the Echo Screen you have to tap the serial number repeatedly to put the device into dev mode -  there doesn't seem to be the same thing for the dot -  and if there is it's not mentioned here.)
It could also just be the sheer number of variables in both the alexa ecosystem, the app and what phone it is on and the network the device is connected to and the dec console. One set of instructions doesn't always cover all the possibilities.'

Answer (score 0):

I have found that when using the skill kit with vscode that I have to go into the web-based skill editor and do a build before it works with an echo device.